# Conditional statement on TextBlock with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'am trying to make an InfoPanel who displays some informations relative to a train's delay.

I have an `Int` variable `TrainDelay` which is converted with a converter `TimeSpanFormatConverter`
I would like to change the displayed Text in my `TextBlock` according to the value of `TrainDelay` using Binding.

this is the conditional statement that i would like to implement :

```
    if TrainDelay > 0  display "Delayed" 
    if TrainDelay < 0  display "In Advance" 
    if TrainDelay = 0  display "On Time"
```

TimeSpanFormatConverter :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int time = int.Parse(value.ToString());
    value = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) || ((TimeSpan)value).Equals(TimeSpan.MinValue))
        return "––:––";
    else
        return ((((TimeSpan)value) < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding TrainDelay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter}}"/>
```

How can I implement this. ?

Comment: Why not take the statements you have posted and put them in your converter to return the string? `if (TrainDelay > 0) return "Delayed";` ?

Comment: I'm novice in c# programming, can you please be more explicit !

Comment: @Jack but I need also to return the  formated value of TrainDelay in "mm:ss" format

Comment: So do you want a separate textbox or appended to the end of the time?

Comment: Either way, just combine the two converters into one

Comment: in a separate textBlock

Comment: Then create another TextBlock, use the converter I posted along with your `TrainDelay` binding, and it will output one of the strings.

Comment: ok i'll try this

Comment: Seems work well, 
thank you @Jack

Comment: I suggest adding some error handling, such as checking the value for `null` and adding a `FallbackValue` to your binding so that you can see if the binding fails at any time.

Comment: Yes, i already added a `FallbackValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int time = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

    if (time > 0)
    {
        return "Delayed";
    } 

    if (time < 0 )
    {
        return "In Advance";
    }

    if (time == 0)
    {
        return "On Time";
    }

    return ""; //Or Argument Exception, your call
}
```